# Distance from nurbs curve to its control points

Tags: nurbs

Is it possible to get distance from nurbs control points to the nurbs curve?
I understand the weights control the shape of the curve but i would like to get the distance to the control points.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: That could get me fired :) But I have something similar to like this:get the closest point to the curve and measure the distance from the control point to it. But am not too sure thats useful

Answer (score 0):

The nurbs curve is defined by the control points, so you just need to run a Point-Curve distance algorithm.

The algorithm is described in "The Nurbs Book", but essentially you just have to minimize this function:

```
    f(u) = C'(u)∙[C(u) - P]
```

where P is the control point, and C is your nurbs curve. C' is the derivative of the curve.

You can use any numerical method to find the minimum of f(u), (Newton, for example)